# How does SE, as a company, deal with negativity?

Tags: discussion, moderators

This might be meta-meta, but it's a serious question.  I ran an online community for a long time (nowhere near this size, of course), and I burned out.  It's too easy to get too emotionally invested.

Without mentioning any specific topics, I see a lot of fingers pointed at SO staff (and, of course, it is ultimately their responsibility to "fix" any "problems").  But some subjects simply have no right or wrong answer, even though the community may be vehemently divided on it.  This causes hostility and can weigh heavily on a team.

How does Stack Exchange Inc, as a company, handle this?  I see some mods/staff get deep into the weeds in comments.  Do you have policies or procedures on this or other specific behaviors unique to running an online community?  Are there mandatory "take a breather" breaks, things like that?  How does this differ for volunteer moderators vs staff?

Comment: They play Ostrich for 6 to 8 years but once they emerge they go all-in ...

Comment: Speaking for mods, we have a leave of absence system that lets the staff and other mods know when we need one, but no mandatory breaks are imposed and there are no restrictions as to how long or short our terms need to be, as ultimately, like you stated moderators are volunteers. I've personally taken a few lengthy (think weeks or months) breaks myself for a variety of reasons and not been judged for it.

Comment: @rene thanks for exemplifying my point...

Comment: Expecting... *drinks heavily*... I know it works for me!

Comment: Just remember, @Paulie_D - [the dose makes the poison](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/822558225639809024)

Comment: That's why daily preventative doses are so important!

Comment: Should this perhaps be migrated to MSE?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Broadly, the company gives us an *amazing* benefit package that hyper encourages good work-life balance, time off when you need it, unlimited sick days and other things. When one looks at the *intent* there, as most of us do, we hopefully realize *the company loves us and wants us to be happy*.

We do have very specific policies about stuff (relationships at work, etc), but our policies tend to be broader so they apply to a large variety of teams and tasks that face them. We all feel stress, it might come from negativity, or code that won't work under a deadline. The feeling is the same, the cause is just different.

So, we walk away, play ping pong, raid the snack bar, have a coffee (or beer), hit the gym, hang out with some coworkers, or just take a few days off. It would really depend with the stress, causes and circumstances.

Sometimes, well let's just say *theoretically* .. someone left Jay Hanlon alone with the blog. We may or may not have anticipated the amount of emotional labor that would bring to the table, which means we may or may not have planned to be sure many hands made lighter work, to check in with one another frequently, and to use our very liberal policies that reinforce our desire for people to love their jobs to get the time that they need to decompress.

More directly? I think some of us are just naturally in a better place to handle that kind of work and (much like honey badgers) really don't mind when bees sting us and cobras bite us, even if we need an occasional nap, because we honestly just love <strike>all of you</strike> honey so darn much.

My personal rule of thumb? If you feel that clenching feeling coming on, it'll pass in 15 minutes if you just play some modded Minecraft. So, I just keep the game up while I work, and occasionally just putter around my base doing the stuff I haven't managed to automate yet while working on new contraptions. My kids love Minecraft too, so it usually turns into a group (a benefit of working from home).

But for everyone, it's something else, and hopefully you'll hear from them too.

Comment: I always kind of wanted to be Christopher Walken. Now I kind of want to be you.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I was going to suggest that, after someone lobbed some really hostile remarks to Jay in particular on _that thread_, he ought to get a few days off to compensate. Now I learn he has unlimited time off, he can award that extra time to himself `:=)`

Comment: Well, he has unlimited _sick_ days, but he'd have to talk to his manager (which would be Joel) if he's going to be out more than 5 days consecutively. We also accrue an _enormous_ amount of vacation time which can be used liberally so, essentially, what you said is true.

Answer (score 59):

One of the nice parts of working remotely is that you can stomp around your house screaming at people and not get fired because those people aren't around to hear you.

Also, I garden.

Comment: *[Shog9's favorite task in the garden after a discussion with rene](https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/08/lawnmower-flowers.jpg.838x0_q80.jpg)*

Comment: I always pictured Shog's favourite way to decompress to be hunting bears with a sawn-off in the Coloradan forests. I like to think that is missing here entirely for legal reasons.

Comment: Somehow, the image of Shog9 running in circles, jumping and stepping on small statues of gold badges while yelling "He *COme**SSS***", came to mind

Comment: I bet no visitor has ever spotted a weed in any of your garden plots….

Comment: Naw, I try to keep my weeds hidden.

Comment: If you ever want to go hiking, [Mt. Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Scott_(Oklahoma)) is only 500 miles away. There's a pretty great view up there, at 2,469 ft...

Comment: I live at 7000'... But OK certainly is lovely!

Answer (score 21):

First, thanks for asking this question.

Second, I'm glad gardening works for Shog, it would send me over the edge. I'm more of a movies and music guy.

Third, interacting with folks on meta has been both very rewarding AND the worst part of my job. As mentioned in [this medium post](https://medium.com/@jfriend/stack-overflows-inclusion-problem-c9b297eb2404), I've had two rough weeks out of just over 52 since I started at Stack. Those two weeks felt like #*%$ (stronger words are needed, but might be blocked). Individual interactions on meta were 100% the cause.

Frequently, some community members can string together some horribly, vile,  hurtful words and ideas under the excuse of "brutal honestly" or "sharing my opinion". These words often malign the intentions and/or the intelligence of hard working people at Stack Overflow. I have felt personally attacked and I have wanted to respond like a mama bear protecting her young (aka my team and the rest of the great folks at SO).

I've been fearful to delete such comments (and in one case did and was accused of censoring someone) so I just walk away. In the early days I told myself, "Certainly someone is going to delete this garbage." But too often it was allowed to stand. Maybe part of the problem is that MSE (in particular) doesn't have clear enough owners the way other communities do. But things get pretty bad here on MSO too, so that's not the only problem.

My experience and the fact that our communities allow this type of stuff to be posted is but an example of the problem. As I said on Medium, I get paid to take it. But some days that's not enough. So, I walk away from meta and throw myself into other aspects of my job or my personal life as a way of safeguarding myself from abuse. I (or any employee at SO, or any member of our community) shouldn't have to put up with this type of treatment.

**Our community can be better than that.**

Comment: I'm sorry Joe. You and your team do a wonderful job. I'll be more careful in the future when I express my self.

Comment: Aw thanks, @rene. Not sure you've ever been a problem, but I appreciate it anyway.

Comment: "Second, I'm glad gardening works for Shog, it would send me over the edge." - opportunity missed, it should be "it would send me over the *hedge*"

Comment: @Sudsy1002 My mind subconsciously inserted the 'h' apparently, I fully thought he had written "over the hedge" until I saw your comment and looked back.

Comment: "I (or any employee at SO, or any member of our community) shouldn't have to put up with this type of treatment. Our community can be better than that." I think 6000 years of history has done a very good job of showing us that this is idealism that stretches well beyond what's realistically achievable, and we've seen in the past 200 years or so that attempts to impose ideals end horribly. Ultimately, the only way forward through wrongs that seems to actually work is to "pick up your cross and bear it," and to do your imperfect best not to inflict wrongs upon others.

Comment: @jpmc26 I didn't mean that everyone who attempts to interact in the community would behave correctly. I simply meant that we, the active participants in the community, can work to be better than the worst elements. This requires us to define and enforce norms of behavior. I could be completely missing your point, but it sounds to me like you're saying people are bad and there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: You haven't missed the point, but I don't think you've understood its implications, either. The members of the community aren't fundamentally any better than non-members. Sometimes we perceive something as an attack when it hits on something unpleasant but true, and it's hard to tell the difference when emotions get in the way. We're all going to find ourselves offended by legitimate points sometimes. It is *vital* to reaching the truth that we accept those negative feelings as something we must deal with personally, rather than something that imposes a requirement on the speaker.

Comment: There *is* a point at which it becomes blatantly obvious that someone is being unreasonable or intentionally hurtful, and I think SO already does a good job of dealing with that sort of response. But beyond that, cracking down on how people choose their words is counterproductive to listening and to learning. Also, as a person in a position of power in this community, it is appropriate that you be willing to draw the line at what you accept directed toward yourself a little further than others to reduce the risk of unintentionally abusing your power, since people in power are imperfect, too.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree that on my own posts I need to let the broader community deal with the crap. However, I think that on any other post I, any other employee, or mod should use their power to set and enforce the community standards.